# Change Appendix name without altering numbering

Tags: appendices

[image]

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{report}

        \begin{document}

        \appendix
        \chapter{Appendix}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{European gymnastics associations 1881 (incl. North America)}
  \tiny
    \begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{LRRRRRR}
    \hline
    Nation & Population & Associations & Members & Gymnasts & Inhabitants per association & Inhabitants per member \bigstrut\\
    \hline
    Germany & 50'000'000 & 1'971 & 170'315 & 86'199 & 25'367 & 293 \bigstrut[t]\\
    France & 37'000'000 & 180   & 18'000 & 6'000 & 205'555 & 2'055 \\
    Italy & 27'700'000 & 92    & 11'871 & -     & 301'087 & 2'333 \\
    North America & 39'000'000 & 172   & 11'313 & 6'901 & 226'745 & 3'447 \\
    Belgium & 5'400'000 & 66    & 7'660 & 5'383 & 81'818 & 704 \\
    Switzerland & 2'600'000 & 119   & 4'000 & 2'600 & 21'850 & 650 \\
    Netherlands & 3'800'000 & 50    & 2'944 & 1'510 & 76'000 & 1'290 \\
    England & 34'000'000 & 50    & -     & -     & 680'000 & - \\
    Sweden & 4'500'000 & 26    & -     & -     & 173'077 & - \bigstrut[b]\\
    \hline
    \end{tabulary}%
\end{table}%

        \end{document}
```

At the moment I have two appendix titles which I would like to change to only one. It should only be named "Appendix". I have found solutions naming it Appendix and losing the Appendix A, but then I also lose the number with A.1, A.2, A.3, ....
How can I have the title "Appendix" but retaining the number with A.1, ...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Loading `titlesec`, you can declare

```
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
```

just after `\appendix`

MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}
\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
\chapter{Appendix}

\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{European gymnastics associations 1881 (incl. North America)}
\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you only want a single title `Appendix`, then the following works and is probably the simplest approach:

[image]

```
\documentclass{report}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\chapter{Some chapter}

\cleardoublepage% Works for oneside or twoside
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{A}% Force chapter to be 'A'
%\phantomsection% If you're using hyperref
\chapter*{Appendix}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \caption{Some table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```