# Renaming appendix in header

Tags: header-footer

[image]

The above picture shows the current state of my header in the Appendix. The title of the Appendix is currently "Appendix" which appears as "Appendix" in the TOC. This should remain that way. However, in the header of the appendix I would like to only appear "Appenidx" without the "Appendix A". Since I only have one appendix and don't need that differentiation in the header.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\nouppercase\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\nouppercase\leftmark} 
\fancyfoot{}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}

   \makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@makechapterhead[1]{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\renewcommand*\@makeschapterhead[1]{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
\chapter{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `\markboth{Appendix}{}` after `\chapter{Appendix}` like in

```
\chapter{Appendix}
\markboth{Appendix}{}
```

Code:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr,titlesec}
\pagestyle{fancy}           %% Added
\fancyhead[RO,RE]{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\nouppercase\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO,LE]{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % remove lines as well
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
}


%% the following is better done with titlesec since you are loading it
%%   Use \titlespacing command for better. I didn't change though.
  \makeatletter
\renewcommand*\@makechapterhead[1]{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\renewcommand*\@makeschapterhead[1]{%
  %\vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright
    \normalfont
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries  #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\appendix
\titleformat{\chapter}{}{}{0pt}{\normalfont\Huge\bfseries}
\chapter{Appendix}
\markboth{Appendix}{}
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \caption{European gymnastics associations 1881 (incl. North America)}
\end{table}%
Some text
\clearpage
Some text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The second choice is not an option for the OP, I think. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/224175/27635.

Comment: Correct. However, the first option works great!

Comment: @karlkoeller I didn't see that. I have changed the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MadJens I have updated the answer.